# Getting an error saying "Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly" while installing numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pip, virtualenv, python-wheel

I am trying to install a specific version of numpy using the command `pip install numpy=1.19.1` in a python virtual environment. But I am getting the following errors

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

How do I solve this? I am using Python 3.9.6 and Pip 21.1.3. And I am on macOS Big Sur.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think NumPy is not yet being prepared for Python 3.9 since they need to check a lot of times. You should try Python 3.7 or 3.8 is better.

See this thread: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17569

**Edit:** Based on the [latest news](https://numpy.org/news/#:%7E:text=NEWS-,NUMPY%201.22.0%20RELEASE,-Dec%2031%2C%202021:%7E:text=The%20Python%20versions%20supported%20by%20this%20release%20are%203.8%2D3.10.) on numpy's website (dated 31st December) Numpy appears to now be supporting python 3.9 and 3.10 as well

Comment: I had the same problem with python 3.10, so installed python 3,8 and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Didn't work for me on python 3.10 within docker slim buster, but works perfectly fine in python 3.8.

Comment: This is from numpy 1.25 onwards I believe. So `pip install numpy>=1.25`

Answer (score 32):

I was facing the same error on my MacBook Air(macOS BigSur) Laptop while installing the Numpy package via integrated terminal of VS Code. And I found the solution:
So previously I was using older version of pip i.e. 19.2.3.
But when I upgraded it to the latest version using command

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and after that when running the command

```
pip install numpy
```

it worked absolutely fine.

At the time running the above commands, my python version was 3.8.2.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well on Python 3.9.10.

Comment: Worked on 3.9 with your solution in Macbook Pro M1.

Comment: Upgrading the 'pip' version was the trick.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Windows, then install Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools, then go to 'Individual components', then tick the latest version of 'Windows 10 SDK', and 'MSVC v142 x64/86 build tools - Latest'. That solved this error for me, except for me this error came when installing discord.py.

Try seeing if it works with Python 3.8 first though, just like Dhananjay's answer. That could save you a lot of storage, because Visual Studio takes up lots of space. If that doesn't work, you can try my answer.

Edit: I just realised, you said you're on Mac. Try this:

- type python -VV in terminal
- It should say something like this:

```
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jun 29 2021, 10:19:25)
[GCC 10.3.0]
```

Whatever it says on the second line is what you will need to install. I use Python on Ubuntu 21.10 on WSL2, which uses GCC 10.3.0, and I have GCC 10.3.0 installed.

Comment: So, does installing `GCC 10.3.0` allow you to "build wheels for numpy" and continue using Python `3.9.x`?

Comment: @Brett Pontarelli Yes. You can actually delete GCC (or whatever other C compiler you used) after you install any extensions that require it.

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to the answers above, switching to Python 3.8 solved the issue. Additionally, because of this issue, I couldn't install `scikit-image` which depends on numpy.

I created a virtual environment of Python 3.8 using `conda` i.e. `conda create -n py38 python=3.8` to switch python version. I have Mac M1, 2020 updated to OS Monterey, version 12.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

yea, I was also using python 3.10 and switched back to python 3.8.

check this link [python/downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/) to download python 3.8

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30075715)